# I have to do performance test of a web based application through Jmeter. To connect to the application , I have to be in Client VPN

Tags: jmeter, vpn

I have to do performance test of a web based application through Jmeter. To connect to the application , I have to be in Client VPN and it has specific proxy to connect. The application will NOT work in Local host..

When I am trying to record it through JMETER I am getting websocket connection lost. Do we need to do setting in JMETER for VPN?

Solution.Do we need to do setting in JMETER for VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can record HTTPS traffic between the browser and the system under test using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)
2. You can make JMeter aware of the "specific proxy" by [either system properties or command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
3. JMeter neither knows nor cares about VPN as long as it can reach the system under test
4. You won't be able to use HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to capture WebSockets, you will have to use i.e. your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and a special JMeter Plugin for example [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/)